# JPA equivalent method for ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there any JPA equivalent method for query like below

JPA equivalent method for

```
SELECT * From Table ORDER BY FIELD(column , 'data1','data2','data3', 'data4')
```

I see options like below available

```
repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "colName"));

repository.findAllOrderByColumnAsc();
```

But method like

```
repository.findAll(Sort.by(SortByColumnValue, {"data3","data2","data1","data4"));
```

is not available

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD` is `MYSQL` specific only, so there is no actual reason for `JPA` that is common specification for multiple vendors to support it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something dynamic and the best way to achieve that is using orders

```
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

    Order StartTimeOrder = new Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "StartTime");
    orders.add(StartTimeOrder);
    Order progDateOrder = new Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ProgDate");
    orders.add(progDateOrder);

    return repository.findAll(Sort.by(orders));
```